# Select values in data frame 1 to a new data frame if certain criteria is met

Tags: r

I am trying to do the followings:

1. take values from the columns `ScanNo` and `Intensity` from `df1`, if `m/z` value meets `df1['m/z'] >= 126.126226) & df1['m/z'] <= 126.129226` to the corresponding `ScanNo` and `TMT126` columns in `df2`;
2. take values from the columns `ScanNo` and `Intensity` from `df1`, if `m/z` value meets `df1['m/z'] >= 127.123261) & df1['m/z'] <= 127.126261`, put the values of `ScanNo` and `Intensity` in `df1` into the correponding `ScanNo` and `TMT127` columns in `df2`.
3. etc

**df1**

```
     ScanNo      m/z Intensity
6         3 126.9017  499.1501
7         3 127.2447  592.0988
8         3 131.0728  576.3497
9         3 131.1089  632.2596
227       5 126.8965  658.6285
228       5 126.9355  650.5634
229       5 128.7293  606.1353
404       7 127.6725  651.5209
405       7 128.9860  615.9063
556       9 128.2417  612.7980
557       9 129.5913  615.2646
749      12 129.7950  579.4946
820      13 128.6606  699.6893
821      13 130.1904  632.3969
822      13 130.3656  561.7806
881      14 131.1699  617.8976
969      16 128.9069  765.4885
970      16 131.0128  628.3944
1200     18 129.1965  579.4517
1324     19 127.9362  588.1160
1407     20 131.5393  605.0532
```

**df2**

```
ScanNo TMT126 TMT127 etc
```

Does anyone know how to do that **using R**? Thanks!

Comment: `r <- (df1$m / df1$z); df1[126.126 <= r & r <= 126.129,]` (is a good start)

Comment: Where is `TMT126` or `TMT127` column? Also how do you want final dataframe to look if  `df1['m/z'] >= 126.126226) & df1['m/z'] <= 126.129226` had 10 rows in it and the other condition had 8 rows.

Comment: `TMT126` and `TMT127` columns are in the **df2**. Based on the criteria I set, there will be either Zero or only one value/row for `TMT126` and `TMT127`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `within` and `ifelse` inside. You probably want `NA`s if the values are not inside the ranges. I create a simplified `m.z` column to demonstrate.

```
df2 <- within(df1, {
  TMT126 <- ifelse(m.z >= 1 & m.z <= 2, m.z, NA)
  TMT127 <- ifelse(m.z >= 3 & m.z <= 4, m.z, NA)
  TMT128 <- ifelse(m.z >= 5 & m.z <= 6, m.z, NA)
  rm(m.z, Intensity)
  })
df2
#    ScanNo TMT128 TMT127 TMT126
# 1       3     NA     NA      2
# 2       3     NA      3     NA
# 3       3     NA      3     NA
# 4       3     NA     NA      2
# 5       3     NA      4     NA
# 6       5     NA      4     NA
# 7       5      6     NA     NA
# 8       5      6     NA     NA
# 9       5      5     NA     NA
# 10      7      5     NA     NA
# 11      9     NA      4     NA
# 12     13     NA     NA      2
# 13     13     NA     NA      2
# 14     13      6     NA     NA
# 15     13     NA      4     NA
# 16     16      5     NA     NA
# 17     16     NA     NA      2
# 18     16     NA     NA      1
# 19     16     NA      4     NA
# 20     19     NA      4     NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(ScanNo = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 19L), m.z = c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 4L), Intensity = c(499.050819190312, 502.115755613237, 
498.921830630967, 500.373553890647, 498.659124958938, 500.670703826751, 
499.295448634045, 499.948336887528, 499.49054987242, 500.160221846888, 
500.036135738485, 500.946913174943, 500.580928969496, 498.996895445679, 
496.507093594431, 500.788140622824, 500.167440904356, 499.120163471469, 
497.046420199033, 499.682652479155)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to help you work with your mass spec data. It uses `dplyr` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
select_scans <- function(data, mz_min, mz_max) {   
  data %>%  # setting up the pipe
    mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)) %>% # convert all columns to numeric if needed
    filter(between(`m_z`, mz_min, mz_max)) %>%  # filtering only the m/z values you want
    select(ScanNo, Intensity) %>% # keeping only the columns you want
    rename(paste0("TM", round(average(mz_min, mz_max), 0)) = Intensity)
    # rename the intensity column like you want
}
```

So, you run

```
df126 <- select_scans(df1, 126.126226, 126.129226)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I ran these scripts, I got an error message: Error in data %>% filter(between("m/z", mz_min, mz_max)) %>% select(ScanNo,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: I forgot to run the `library(dplyr)` first. But now I got an new error:  `Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].` Do you know how to solve that? Thanks!

Comment: @Chemistlearnstocode - It sounds like your m/z values are not stored as numeric? I updated my answers to take care of it.